# Documentation of conditionals

Tags: python, conditional-statements, python-sphinx

Is it possible to document conditional statements and other statements in a function using Sphinx?

If not, is there any other python library which has such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a description of them to the description in the docstring at the appropriate level - this will be carried over to the Spinx documentation.